# Android BasicCookieStore, Cookies and HttpGet

Tags: java, android, cookies, http-get, cookiestore

I have a an app that should send a GET request to a URL and send some cookies along with it. I've been looking at a few code examples for BasicCookieStore and Cookie classes, but I'm not able to figure out how to use them. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

To use cookies you need something along the lines of:

```
CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpContext ctx = new BasicHttpContext();
ctx.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
HttpGet get = new HttpGet("your URL here");

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(get,ctx);
```

And if you want to keep cookies between requests, you have to reuse `cookieStore` and `ctx` for every request.

Also, you may read your `cookieStore` to see what's inside:

```
List<Cookie> cookies = cookieStore.getCookies();
if( !cookies.isEmpty() ){
    for (Cookie cookie : cookies){
        String cookieString = cookie.getName() + " : " + cookie.getValue();
        Log.info(TAG, cookieString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I have not fully understood the concept of cookies, but i have a two strings which I want to send to the url as name-value pairs. From this code, I can't understand how to do that. Could you please guide me?

Comment: @RameezHussain you may use `addCookie()` method of `CookieStore`: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/CookieStore.html