# Android httpclient login and use cookies for further processes

Tags: android, cookies, httpclient

I am developing an app which includes logins activity and main activity.
If the user login for the first time, the app saves username and pass in sharedPrefs. And on the next startup, login activity uses those username and password, if server returns true(in xml, getEntity) main activity intent starts. After login, I want to interact with webpage using cookies set in startup login. As far as I searched through the web, they say that I should use the same httpclient in order not to lose cookies. I tried it and but couldnt manage. So, can I use cookies without using same httpclient?

**General logic of my app:**

```
httpclient.execute("http://www.abc.com/index.php?process=login&user="+variable1+"&pass="+variable1); 

//here I get the entity of this response and I parse that return value, after that, if(login==true)--> go on...
//here I have to read all page from website which is protected by user authentication(by cookies).(ex:index.php?process=getmymessages)
//But I did not manage that. At this point what is your suggestions?
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider to use the same HttpClient via a Singleton solution like this:

```
public enum MyAppHttpClient {
    INSTANCE;

    private HttpClient configuredHttpClient = null;

    public HttpClient getConfiguredHttpClient() {
        if (configuredHttpClient == null) {
            try {
                HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 5000);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 5000);
                configuredHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                configuredHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            }
        }

        return configuredHttpClient;
    }
}
```

You can call MyAppHttpClient.INSTANCE.getConfiguredHttpClient() everywhere where you need it.

If it is not enough, you can manage the cookies by yourself, BasicCookieStore class is a good starting point, and you can check this thread:
[Android BasicCookieStore, Cookies and HttpGet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556712/android-basiccookiestore-cookies-and-httpget)

I hope it helps to you.

Comment: How can i define a new HttpClient by using "MyAppHttpClient.INSTANCE.getConfiguredHttpClient()" ? I tried this way but it didnt work: DefaultHttpClient htpost = MyAppHttpClient.INSTANCE.getConfiguredHttpClient();

Comment: Between try{} block, where is the "configuredHttpClient" assigned value? It maintains null value, can you update the code again?

Comment: You can use it this way:
HttpClient httpclient = ClaimHttpClient.INSTANCE.getHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(someUrl);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the code, the last line of the try{} block has changed to this: configuredHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);

Comment: Thx. It works. But i got error if i try to execute new httpget. Error is : SingleClientConnManager(1402): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated. How can i avoid from this happening?

Comment: Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612573/exception-using-httprequest-execute-invalid-use-of-singleclientconnmanager-c
It says that: "You need to consume the response body before you can reuse the connection for another request. You should not only read the response status, but read the response InputStream fully to the last byte whereby you just ignore the read bytes."